# What are the "User Defined Rules" mentioned in the Azure Fundamentals Skills Measured document?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

In the document [Exam AZ-900: Microsoft Azure Fundamentals - Skills Measured](https://query.prod.cms.rt.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RE3VwUY), under the section "Understand security, privacy, compliance and trust", and the subsection "Understanding securing network connectivity in Azure", the third bullet reads "User Defined Rules (UDR)".

I searched extensively on the Azure website and with a google search, with no result. What are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a typo. The correct expression is [User-Defined Routes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview#user-defined).

Comment: It's a pity that they don't bother changing this. The new document from May 28 (https://query.prod.cms.rt.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RE3VwUY) still contains that typo. And they want us to pay money for that stupid exam...

Comment: Yes, incredible that is still there. Sigh.